# setContentView(R.layout.main); - cannot find package

Tags: android, netbeans

I have never used Android Studio before and have always been coding using NetBeans.
I need to create an app for Android, so I decided to use NetBeans. I created new project and it is 'empty' for now, however I have an error:

```
package Fridge.Freezer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

The error is in setContentView(R.layout.main); - cannot find package. Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong? Clean and build does not work.

Answer (score 0):

erase your package name at the top and try to add it to getting the suggestion package import by shortcut Control + Enter beside "R"

Answer (score 0):

Try checking following component in your project directory

- `R.java` file
- folder named `layout`
- layout xml file named `main.xml`main

PS Since your are starting a fresh project, I would suggest you to start at Android Studio.

Comment: OK, I found all of these but I am lost what to do now.

Comment: If you are starting fresh project how about using Android Studio . In long run, you might find less people who have knowledge about Netbeans for Android while most of the people prefer Android studio for android

Comment: I tried Android Studio and I completely do not understand how to use it.. :(

Comment: Keep trying. Trust me you won't regret. :) Here is the good link for android studio tutorial [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/120177/beginning-android-development-tutorial-installing-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

I tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it again. It did not work. The solution was to restart IDE.